# Using jQuery filter outside of a table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, search, filter

I've found lots of examples of how to use jQuery filter on tables, but I can't find out how to do so on items not inside a table. For example, I have cards which I have to search through.

I have tried to adapt code from [this w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp) and it seems to work when I type the word 'second' but not the word 'first'.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#txtSearch").on("keyup", function() {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#milestoneCard").filter(function() {
                    $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });
        });
```

I was wondering if this was possible and if so what I'd have to change.

I've searched around quite a bit and while I'm sure it's possible, I can't seem to find out how in my case.

I have reproduced it in the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6qp4s3op/10/)

Comment: That is a horrible example of using `filter()`. They should have just used `each()` because they aren't actually filtering anything. [filter(function)](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) expects a `return` in the callback to return a reduced set of elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same `id` for two components.
Change it to `class="col-md-4 milestoneCard"` and your selector to `$(".milestoneCard")` and it will work.
The `id` property should be unique across the whole page and the selector will only grab the first one it finds.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple of the same id's on a page. Therefore the JS will not work as expected.  ID's are unique, classes are able to be repeated.

to fix this, try making milestoneCard a class instead of an id in your html, as shown here

HTML

```
<input type="search" id="txtSearch">
<div class="col-md-4 milestoneCard">
    <div class="card card-body bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
        <h3 id="searchTitle">First</h3>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <p>Due date:{{dueDate}}</p>
        <p>Completed date:{{compDate}}</p>
        <form action="/plannerHomepage" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="compId" value="{{id}}">
            <input type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="completed" style="margin-top:1em;" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 milestoneCard">
    <div class="card card-body bg-light" style="margin-bottom: 1em;">
        <h3 id="searchTitle">Second</h3>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <p>Due date:{{dueDate}}</p>
        <p>Completed date:{{compDate}}</p>
        <form action="/plannerHomepage" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="compId" value="{{id}}">
            <input type="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="completed" style="margin-top:1em;" />
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And your JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtSearch").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".milestoneCard").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Or see the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/34ha5sxm/)